# My application is showing EXTRA info...which is NOT needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an action called 'list' and is defined like

```
def list
   @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")  
end
```

And my list view looks like

```
<div>
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <%= link_to("Add new subject",{:action=>'new'},:class=>'action new')%>
  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header"> 
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>  
     <tr>
     <td><%=subject.position%></td>   
     <td><%=subject.name%></td>   
     <td class="center"><%=subject.visible ? 'Yes':'No' %></td>
     <td class="center"><%=subject.pages.size%></td>
     <td class="actions">
       <%=link_to "Show",{:action=>'show',:id=>subject.id},:class=>'action show'%>
       <%=link_to "Edit",{:action=>'edit',:id=>subject.id},:class=>'action edit'%>
      <%=link_to "Delete",{:action=>'delete',:id=>subject.id},:class=>'action delete'%>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <%end%>   

 </table>
</div>
```

So the problem is that besides getting an organized list of all the subjects nearby my link "Add subject" the page is printing all the information that *@subjetcs* brings from the controller.

Which of course is not a very good idea...I can't figure out why is that happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line `<%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>`. Because you've got `<%=`, the return value of that line - which is `@subjects` - should be written into the document.

Use `<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>` instead to suppress the output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equals sign from the `<%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>` line.

ERB outputs everything within `<%= ... %>` tags to the page. So in this case, the return value of `@subjects.each` is written to the page. Thus, write your loop like this instead:

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This applies to all statements that do stuff rather than output stuff to the page. For example, you would write an if statement as:

```
<% if some_condition %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

rather than as:

```
<%= if some_condition %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>`

should be:

`<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>`

The equals sign tells ERB that the code should output something. You want to omit that in the iterator.